# MySQL SELECT Multiple DISTINCT COUNT

Tags: mysql

Here is what I'm trying to do. I have a table with user assessments which may contain duplicate rows. I'm looking to only get `DISTINCT` values for each user.

In the example of the table below. If only user_id 1 and 50 belongs to the specific location, then only the unique video_id's for each user should be returned as the `COUNT`. User 1 passed video 1, 2, and 1. So that should only be 2 records, and user 50 passed video 2. So the total for this location would be 3. I think I need to have two `DISTINCT's` in the query, but am not sure how to do this.

```
+-----+----------+----------+
| id  | video_id | user_id  |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 1   |       1  |        1 |
| 2   |       2  |       50 |
| 3   |       1  |      115 |
| 4   |       2  |       25 |
| 5   |       2  |        1 |
| 6   |       6  |       98 |
| 7   |       1  |        1 |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

This is what my current query looks like.

```
$stmt2 = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_assessment.id)
FROM user_assessment
LEFT JOIN user ON user_assessment.user_id = user.id
WHERE user.location = '$location'");
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($video_count);
$stmt2->fetch();
$stmt2->close();
```

So my query returns all of the count for that specific location, but it doesn't omit the non-unique results from each specific user.

Hope this makes sense, thanks for the help.

Comment: No solution but an optimization: use INNER JOIN. It is faster than LEFT JOIN, and the effect is the same, since you use the joined table in the WHERE clause.

Comment: And did you know line breaks are allowed in SQL queries?

Comment: @GolezTrol, yes thank you. It's just how I copied the code that I lost the line breaks. I've edited my post to make it a little easier to read.

Comment: @Jako . . . Your description and your sample query/data have nothing to do with each other.  You use words like "location" and "video", and yet these are not in the query.  Can you revise the question to make it clearer what you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry about that, tweaked the question a bit to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below joins a sub-query that fetches the distinct videos per user. Then, the main query does a sum on those numbers to get the total of videos for the location.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(video_count)
FROM 
  user u
  INNER JOIN 
  ( SELECT
      ua.user_id,
      COUNT(DISTINCT video_id) as video_count
    FROM
      user_assessment ua
    GROUP BY
      ua.user_id) uav on uav.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE 
  u.location = '$location'
```

Note, that since you already use bindings, you can also pass `$location` in a bind parameter. I leave this to you, since it's not part of the question. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ua.video_id, ua.user_id)
FROM user_assessment ua
INNER JOIN user ON ua.user_id = user.id
WHERE user.location = '$location'
```

You can write a lot of things inside a `COUNT` so don't hesitate to put what you exactly want in it. This will give the number of different couple `(video_id, user_id)`, which is what you wanted if I understood correctly.

Comment: +1 I wasn't sure and didn't have a database at hand to test, but if this works, it is better than my answer. More compact, more clear and probably faster.