# MySQL count useragents with distinct IP addresses

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I built an app that records user events. Each event contains the user's IP address and their useragent (and other data like a timestamp and other stuff that is not relevant here).

I would like to use a single query to get (in one row) the total number of events, the number of distinct IP addresses, and the number of iPad users (number of distinct IP/useragent combinations where ugeragent contains "iPad").

#### Sample table: EVENTS

```
id    ip         useragent
=================================
1    "x1"    "blabla iPad blabla"
2    "x2"    "blabla"
3    "x3"    "blabla iPad blabla"
4    "x3"    "blabla iPad blabla"
5    "x3"    "blabla iPad blabla"
```

#### Result expected

```
event_count    ip_count    ipad_users
=======================================
    5             3            2
```

---

#### My attempts

The following query returns **4** iPad users because it does not check IP+useragent.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as event_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as ip_count,
    COUNT(IF( useragent LIKE '%iPad%', 1, NULL )) as ipad_users
FROM events
```

This one only returns **1** iPad user because I'm doing it wrong.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as event_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as ip_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip AND IF( useragent LIKE '%iPad%', 1, NULL )) as ipad_users
FROM events
```

How can I do this? The closest related question I could find on SO was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918459/mysql-select-multiple-distinct-count), but I cannot figure it out.

### SQL Fiddle

This set of data should return 3 iPad users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want a condition `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as event_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as ip_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT (case when useragent LIKE '%iPad%' then ip end)) as ipad_users
FROM events;
```

That is, count the distinct number of `ip`s when the user agent is an iPad.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I did not know about the `CASE` statement. I was afraid I would have to do nested selects, but this does the job! I'll accept this answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @blex . . . You could write this as `count(distinct if(useragent like '%iPad%', ip, NULL))`.  I prefer the `case` because it is more flexible (it supports multiple clauses) and it is ANSI standard so it works across more databases.  The key is the conditional statement inside the `count(distinct)`.